# Check String if the format is "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss" in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datetime, tryparse

How to check if the given string is in a valid customized format "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"?

For example:

```
2013-09-09 05:25:40
```

is in a valid format.

and

```
09-09-2013 05:25:40
```

is invalid format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTime.TryParseExact() for this.

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(yourDate, "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
   // DateTime parsed, dateValue contains the parsed DateTime
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bibhu, what must be the value of the dateValue variable if the "yourDate" variable contains the input "2013-09-09 05:25:40"?

Comment: @ajdeguzman - dateValue contains the DateTime value equivalent to the date and time contained in yourDate. Check out this MSDN link for more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx